# What does "Knallerfrauen" mean?

Tags: meaning, culture

[Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Knallerfrauen) doesn't seem to make sense with this word. I found [this comedy show](https://www.youtube.com/user/Knallerfrauen) that I think It's hilarious, which its name is this word.

What does "Knallerfrauen" mean?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Knaller, meaning 2

Comment: Ich nehme an, viele Deutsche dürften den Ausdruck gar nicht kennen. Ich lese das Wort hier zum ersten Mal.

Comment: The interesting question is not whether you *know* it, the question is what you *associate* with it hearing it for the first time?

Comment: "Knallerfrauen" is also a comedy show in german tv.. *edit: I'm sorry, I just read the topic of the question ^^

Comment: @rogermue Deine Vermutung betrifft nicht nur Deutsche, sondern auch Deutschsprachige aus anderen Ländern. Ich bin Österreicher und habe dieses Wort auch noch nie gehört. Das ist auch kein Wunder, weil das Wort »knallen« in Österreich ohnehin kaum verwendet wird. Selbiges gilt natürlich auch für alle Komposita die das Wort »knallen« enthalten.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast  Dürfte bei mir ein Generationsproblem sein. Die Sorache der jungen Generation entwickelt sich rasant.

Comment: @rogermue Der auslösende Grund warum ich meinen Kommentar geschrieben habe war um darauf aufmerksam zu machen, dass »Deutsche« und »Deutschsprachige« nicht dasselbe sind. Würden wir uns über die englische Sprache unterhalten und wärest du Engländer würdest du kaum schreiben "I guess that many english people don't know the term." Aber sehr viele Deutsche tun leider so, als wäre Deutscher zu sein und Deutsch zu sprechen dasselbe. Das kommt in deutschsprachigen Regionen außerhalb Deutschlands gar nicht gut an.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast Du hast völlig recht. Wenn man scnnell schreibt, denkt man nicht an alles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Knallerfrauen" is best translated with the word (she is like a) "bombshell", and is (rarely) used in the same context with a hint of humor in it.

Similar word context:

- "Sie ist ein Knaller" (she is a bombshell)
- "Ich bin verknallt" (I am in love)

The hint of humor comes from the fact, that "Knall" is also used to describe that someone is crazy:

"Du hast einen Knall" (you are nuts)

Comment: A "Knaller" is also a little explosive thing that makes a lot of noise. It's often used by kids acommpanying the fireworks in the night of New Year's Eve.

Answer (score 9):

Can't say better than [here](http://www.italki.com/question/146691):

> "Knaller"Frau is kind of a comedic approach. On one hand, it can mean
>   a "hot" woman, but also a woman that is a little weird, in a loud,
>   noisy and outgoing way.
>
> Alltogether, it is a mixture of "hot", "outgoing" and "strong".

Frau, Plural: Frauen

Comment: And in addition, a *Knaller* is a *Joke* - often used in a way that indicates that the joke was so bad it actually made it funny again.

Answer (score 4):

Knaller and/or Kracher also have been used to describe a "joke", most commonly on parties (mainly in the past, I think. 70's? 80's?).

This is highly informal and can be compared to "Schenkelklopfer", "Partykracher" etc.

I don't know if it is part of "Knallerfrauen" or a comedy show itself, but there's also something called "Ladykracher" which does, in my opinion, mean pretty much the same.

Both are Women making setup-comedy and the title describes this pretty much.

Comment: I love the connotation in `user6212`'s answer that correctly states, that *Einen Knall haben* also means *to be a littly weird/crazy*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes, but i do not think this is actually intended

Comment: That's why I like it - I never actually thought of it, but you knowing the show it would make sense if it had been intended.

Comment: For completeness: [Ladykracher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladykracher) and [Knallerfrauen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knallerfrauen) are two different comedy shows that are conceptually quite similar (both consist of many single scenes that draw their humor from somewhat absurd situations and behaviours, and both are centered around a female comedian who appears in many roles, supported by a small number of recurring actors and actresses; moreover, both shows happen to run on the same TV channel in Germany, [Sat 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sat.1)).

Answer (score 1):

Knaller --> Das ist ja voll der Knaller.
Knall --> Loud noise usually resulting from an impact or explosion.

Knaller - Frauen --> More than one woman that makes an impact or explosion. Basically making waves, being hard to ignore, being very entertaining. See christian.s answer in relation to hitting your tights when something is very funny. This usually makes a Knall.

Answer (score 1):

"Knall" (meaning "bang") has the power to make almost everything following it sound exciting, dangerous or hilarious. This first struck me when I read Otfried Preußler's "Der Räuber Hotzenplotz" where they have a sequence about "Knallpilze" ("bang mushrooms"). Nobody has ever heared of Knallpilze, but the word "Knall" immediately conveys a certain connotation.

And christian.s is right: Knall and Krach (meaning "noise") are pretty much interchangeable as a prefix. Except for the word ordering and the plural "Ladykracher" (think: "Kracherladies") and "Knallerfrauen" invoke the same feelings. Both aren't official German words.

"Knallen" has the additional meaning of "fucking" which "krachen" does not have (i.e. "Knallerfrauen" is a bit juicier). So when you ever want to promote a hilarious "foo", call it "Knallerfoo" and you'll get a lot more bang.

And I agree "Knallerfrauen" is one of the best Comedies we have, seconed by "Ladykracher".